How to send email with msgraph SDK from Python
I am trying to build an application which processes and resends messages from a user's mail inbox.
I tried following the sample code (below). It seems, however, that one of the .py files referenced in the sample code is missing. Because I need to include attachments, using the requests library to do the same job would be very uncomfortable.
The sample code:
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.models.send_mail_post_request_body import SendMailPostRequestBody
from msgraph.generated.models.message import Message
from msgraph.generated.models.item_body import ItemBody
from msgraph.generated.models.recipient import Recipient
from msgraph.generated.models.email_address import EmailAddress

graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credentials, scopes)

request_body = SendMailPostRequestBody(
    message = Message(
        subject = "Meet for lunch?",
        body = ItemBody(
            content_type = BodyType.Text,
            content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
        ),
        to_recipients = [
            Recipient(
                email_address = EmailAddress(
                    address = "frannis@contoso.com",
                ),
            ),
        ],
        cc_recipients = [
            Recipient(
                email_address = EmailAddress(
                    address = "danas@contoso.com",
                ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
    save_to_sent_items = False,
)

await graph_client.me.send_mail.post(request_body)


The is no SendMailPostRequestBody class in the msgraph module.

Your import statement should be
from msgraph.generated.users.item.send_mail.send_mail_post_request_body import SendMailPostRequestBody

You can take a look at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python/issues/391 which talks about this issue and also include some sample code that should work.
